# PHP not showing within the data part of a chart.js

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I have managed to get both PHP and JavaScript code working on the same page. In the top of the page on the left you can see that my figures from my php tables are being pulled out correctly however, the moment I go to paste the php code inside of where the table 'data' needs to be kept it doesn't work even though surrounded in php tags.

[image: Screenshot shows database figures being pulled out top of page:]

```
        <?php
    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "x", "y", "z");

    $query = "SELECT * FROM `checkPointMod`";


    $result = $conn -> query($query);


    while($row = $result -> fetch_assoc()) 
      {
        echo $row['mod1']."<br>";
        echo $row['mod2']."<br>";
        echo $row['mod3']."<br>";
        echo $row['mod4']."<br>";
        echo $row['mod5']."<br>";
        echo $row['mod6']."<br>";
      }



    $conn -> close();
    ?>


    <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en-GB">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.3/Chart.min.js"></script>

        </head>

        <body style="background-color: lightgrey;">


    <div class="col-md-4 text-center">Third of Page - Middle section with progress bar
        <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
            datasets: [{
                label: '# of Votes',
                data: [<?php echo $row['mod1']?>, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
                backgroundColor: [
                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)'
                ],
                borderColor: [
                    'rgba(255,99,132,1)'
                ],
                borderWidth: 1
            }]
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero:true
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    });
    </script>

    </html>
```

**Update:** - I've gone to inspect element to see what the output is and it's seen here, I also placed mod2 in to see if 6 would appear...

[image]

Comment: Are you positive it doesn't work? Because according to the output at the top, `$row['mod1']` is `0`, so I'd expect the red bar to be pretty much non-existent. When you check your page source code, does it say `data: [0, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],`?

Comment: Hi @ChrisG yes i've gone to inspect element and it's just blank I've updated the screenshot in the main question :(

Comment: save your results to a new variable since you want to use them outside the while loop. Like `$mod1=$row['mod1'];` and echo that in your javascript.

Comment: @DimitrisFilippou So I tried to place that line of code outside of the while loop, just below it, and call `<?php echo $mod1 ?>` and the source code still shows blank :(

Comment: Can you do a `var_dump($row);` inside the while and show us the results?

Comment: @DimitrisFilippou Results are: `array(8) { ["checkPID"]=> string(1) "6" ["mod1"]=> string(1) "0" ["mod2"]=> string(1) "6" ["mod3"]=> string(1) "0" ["mod4"]=> string(1) "3" ["mod5"]=> string(1) "2" ["mod6"]=> string(1) "1" ["idUsers"]=> string(1) "1" }`

Comment: You must place `$mod1=$row['mod1'];` inside your while loop or try the answer posted by Chris G

Comment: Dimitris and Chris BOTH of these worked so thank you both so much,   I mean I don't know enough about JavaScript to know which one is best to use but thank you both!!!! :) one happy girl right here!

Comment: Glad it's working :) Mine might be a bit more future-proof, in case the db table gains some more rows.

Comment: Yeah Chris' answer is definately more future proof i just wanted to point out to you that the variable `$row` exists only inside the while loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I missed that `$row` only exists inside that while loop.

Replace your while loop with this:

```
$rows = [];
while ($row = $result -> fetch_assoc()) $rows[] = $row;
```

Down in your Javascript code, add this at the top:

```
const data = <?= json_encode($rows, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK) ?>;
```

You should end up with this in your page source:

```
const data = [{ "checkPID": 6, "mod1": 0, "mod2": 6, "mod3": 0, "mod4": 3, "mod5": 2, "mod6": 1, "idUsers": 1 }];
```

Now you can do this in your Chart setup:

```
data: Object.keys(data[0]).filter(key => key.startsWith("mod")).map(key => data[0][key]),
```